# How to iterate in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration

I would like to iterate.

`@some_value` outputs the following result:

```
{
  "Meta" => {
    "Query" => "java",
    "ResultOffset" => "1",
    "NumResults" => "1",
    "TotalResults" => "21931"
  }
}
```

I need to retrieve the value of each individual value. For example:

```
java
1
1
21931
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [each method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002861).

```
@some_value['Meta'].each do |k, v|
    puts v
end
```

Which will loop through every of your entry and execute the code inside the do/end for every of them.
Here it'll display the value of the element.

Comment: i need to display based on key for example @something of Query should return java . The above statement just display the values

Comment: This isn't a very good example, since this would be much better accomplished by a simple `puts @some_value['Meta'].values`

Comment: Yeah. But he wants to iterate and do something else than just display the content of the hash.

Comment: The `k` and `v` are short for key and value in case anyone's wondering. Block parameter names tend to be shorter than normal variable names.

Answer (score 6):

```
@some_value["Meta"].values
```

output is array

```
["java", "1", "1", "21931"]
```

Answer (score 5):

[Hash#each_value](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002862)

```
@some_value['Meta'].each_value { |v| p v }
```